# SpringBoot thymeleaf gives TemplateInputException，when template not exist

Tags: java

Firstly, thymeleaf works well for my project. I have confiured the error.html file. And when access to some addresses which not exist, it would redirect to error.html. But there is a TemplateInputException in the log file at the same time.
[Exception log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijeqx.png)
[Exception log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkBhr.png)

My question is: How do I avoid this exception log?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one configuration in your application.properties file :

```
 logging.level.root=OFF
 logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
 #You can list the packages with which level you want
```

Also just not to turn off logs you can write your own global ExceptionHandling
with @ControllerAdvice 
Here is the link with sample:

https://dzone.com/articles/global-exception-handling-with-controlleradvice

Here is all list of tomcat properties for spring boot :

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=false # Enable access log.
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd # Date format to place in the log file name.
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=common # Format pattern for access logs.
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log # Log file name prefix.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rename-on-rotate=false # Whether to defer inclusion of the date stamp in the
 file name until rotate time.
server.tomcat.accesslog.request-attributes-enabled=false # Set request attributes for the IP address,
 Hostname, protocol, and port used for the request.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true # Whether to enable access log rotation.
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log # Log file name suffix.
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns= # Comma-separated list of additional patterns that match
 jars to ignore for TLD scanning.
server.tomcat.background-processor-delay=10s # Delay between the invocation of backgroundProcess
 methods. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
server.tomcat.basedir= # Tomcat base directory. If not specified, a temporary directory is used.
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=10\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
 192\\.168\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
 169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
 127\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
 172\\.1[6-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
 172\\.2[0-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\
 172\\.3[0-1]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1\\
 ::1 # Regular expression that matches proxies that are to be trusted.
server.tomcat.max-connections=10000 # Maximum number of connections that the server accepts and
 processes at any given time.
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB # Maximum size of the HTTP post content.
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=2MB # Maximum amount of request body to swallow.
server.tomcat.max-threads=200 # Maximum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=10 # Minimum amount of worker threads.
server.tomcat.port-header=X-Forwarded-Port # Name of the HTTP header used to override the original port
 value.
Spring Boot Reference Guide
2.1.0.RELEASE Spring Boot 339
server.tomcat.protocol-header= # Header that holds the incoming protocol, usually named "X-ForwardedProto".
server.tomcat.protocol-header-https-value=https # Value of the protocol header indicating whether the
 incoming request uses SSL.
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=true # Whether requests to the context root should be redirected by
 appending a / to the path.
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header= # Name of the HTTP header from which the remote IP is extracted. For
 instance, `X-FORWARDED-FOR`.
server.tomcat.resource.allow-caching=true # Whether static resource caching is permitted for this web
 application.
server.tomcat.resource.cache-ttl= # Time-to-live of the static resource cache.
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8 # Character encoding to use to decode the URI.
server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects= # Whether HTTP 1.1 and later location headers generated by a call
```

Comment: thanks, I tried, but it not works.

Comment: Updated an answer please try

Comment: Actually, there are two error records, i hava updated in my question. When configure "logging.level.org.thymeleaf=OFF", the first one disappeared, but the second one not. For "log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf=OFF", not work. Thanks.

Comment: Does it helped ?

Comment: still not work...

Comment: For me those config is working

Comment: Could you share your Exceptionhandler ?

Comment: I didn't set any Exceptionhandler.

Comment: Could you share your configs?

Comment: "logging.level.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase=OFF"  this configure works

Comment: Nice but in this case you are excluding all tomcat logs

Comment: Is there anyway like this?#tomcat访问日志
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=D:/logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=xcloud-payservice-tomcat-access.
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=common
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Also you can use '@ExceptionHandler in @ControllerAdvice' and then catch those specific exception and handle or skip it if you want

Comment: Also attached list of all properties for tomcat for spring boot

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try.